# Ruby on Rails 4 find with order and limit equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need very fast to update my app controller to rails 4, but i didn't know how to write all this line in new rails 4 style: with order_by with conditions and with limit, in web i search for fast, and all part's together - didn't find. How could i translate this from rails 3 to rails 4?

in controller i have

```
@news = Article.find(:all, conditions: { text: "example" }, order_by: "created_at", limit: 4 )
```

i didn't must to use conditions in 4, only where, but how to append :all, order_by and limit to it? What is a right syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Arel (https://github.com/rails/arel) everything can be appended.  The various clauses are described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

```
@news = Article.where(text: 'example').order(:created_at).limit(4)
```

Note that this returns a query clause that does not actually query the database until you specifically request the data.

Answer (score 8):

From the old ActiveRecord style:

```
@news = Article.find(:all, conditions: { text: "example" }, order_by: "created_at", limit: 4 )
```

To the new:

```
@news = Article.where(text: "example").order(:created_at).limit(4)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this might do the trick:

```
@news = Article.where(text: 'example').order(:created_at).limit(4)
```

Comment: You don't need to call :all and the order wasn't :desc

Comment: I've modified and changed the issues you found